# BxSlider callback onSlideBefore not working on last slide when on infinite loop

Tags: jquery, bxslider

```
slider = $('.bxslider').bxSlider({
            pager: false,
            infiniteLoop: false,
            adaptiveHeight: true,
            hideControlOnEnd: true,
            onSlideBefore: function(currentSlide, OldIndex, currentSlideHtmlObject) {   

                if(currentSlideHtmlObject != 0) {
                    readings(currentSlideHtmlObject);
                }
            }
        });
```

`readings` returns content from ajax call and appends it to div inside the respective slide .. it is working except on the last slide, the content is being appended on the `<li>` with `bx-clone` class. When I set the `infiniteloop` to false the content appends to div just fine. Any help?